# Error message: Message: javascript error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentNode')

Tags: python

Error message: Message: javascript error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentNode')

I've executed capturing screenshots using chromewebdriver() and while executing the above error occurred. Please solve anyone. Thankyou.

Comment: Can you share some code that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Chrome web driver sounds like Selenium. Are you sure the element you're looking for has loaded before you look for it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.